# Does the page that links to my login page need to https?

Tags: authentication, http, websites

So I realise the login ajax call must be https, and the page that ajax call is made from should also be https to prevent a man in the middle potentially changing the page and changing the form that submits the login for example. So does that mean the page where the link to the login page also must be https to prevent that link to the login page from potentially being compromised?!

This can obviously go on ad infinitum so it sort of suggests the entire site must be https to be truly secure from these types of attacks?

Comment: This almost looks like a duplicate of the question to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515338/363217

Comment: There is a fairly good article from Mozilla available at https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2016/01/28/no-more-passwords-over-http-please/ about this specific problem

Comment: In addition to serving everything over HTTPS you should also use [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Comment: Why the down vote!? People really should explain why they have downvoted to help improve this and future questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... it sort of suggests the entire site must be https to be truly secure from these types of attacks?

Yes, that is exactly the case. All relevant pages on this site (i.e. all in the path to submitting the sensitive information) must be https **only**, i.e. it should not even be possible to access these pages with http because otherwise tools like sslstrip could be used.

For a nice article on how not to do it and why not I recommend [Thank you Waitrose, now fix your insecure site](http://www.troyhunt.com/2016/01/thank-you-waitrose-now-fix-your.html).

Comment: Interesting that even banks do not seem to be doing this, eg hsbc.co.uk is http and I can click login from that page.

Comment: @Sutty1000: "Interesting" was this called 5 years ago. Today this is called "incompetence" because you can still access the login page with plain http on this site (i.e. sslstrip would work).